# Custom fonts on mobile working on some pages but not on others

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I'm using WordPress to build a site https://triclimb.co.uk for my employer. We're using a custom font for selected bits of the site such as headings etc. The font is Gabbaland.

The issue I'm facing is that the font is working perfectly on the home page and other pages across the site (both on desktop and mobile), but on selected pages of the site the font doesn't work on mobile devices.

Example of where the font doesn't work: https://www.triclimb.co.uk/gallery/ the heading 'triclimb on instagram' should be using gabbaland

I can't replicate the issue in any browser on a desktop, I can only see it on a mobile device.

Could anyone help me out? Really confused as to why the font is working on some pages but not others.

Comment: make sure path is proper

Answer (score 0):

Two of the font files throwing 404 error for fonts in console. Please double check wheather you integrated gabbaland font family properly.

Comment: I only have two fonts, both located here triclimb.co.uk/gabbaland-webfont.woff and triclimb.co.uk/gabbaland-webfont.woff2 Both working fine, and these are the ones referenced in the css @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gabbaland';
    src: url('gabbaland-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('gabbaland-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}